# Need an efficient query in the following case

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Have 3 tables

**Table A**

```
id | value
-----------
   |
```

**Table B**

```
id|value|A_id(fk to A)
--------------
  |     |
```

**Table C**

```
id|value|B_id(FK to B)|timestamp
--------------------------------
  |     |             |
```

I have written a query to find out all latest distinct C values using the following query

```
select A.id, B.id, C.timestamp, C.value
from A,B,C 
where A.id = B.A_id
and B.id = C.B_id
where C.value in (select distinct value from C c2 where c2.value = c.value and c2.value is not null)
and c.timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from C c3 where c3.value = c.value);
```

except IDs none of the other columns are having indexes. Right now this query takes about 2 hrs or more to run, because the number of distinct C values are 221000 records. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct A.id, B.id, c.timestamp, c.value FROM 
(
SELECT  c.value,  MAX(c.timestamp) AS max_timestamp FROM c
WHERE NOT c.value IS NULL
GROUP BY  c.value) c1 INNER JOIN c ON c1.value = c.value AND c1.max_timestamp = c.timestamp
    inner join b ON B.id = C.B_id
    inner join a ON A.id = B.A_id
```

Comment: Would this look for distinct C.value? because I'll have a lot of c.values which are repeating. could you also please explain me how ths will be efficient than the one I have?

Comment: have you tried my solution? how many records with max(timestamp) ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please explain why it was so efficient? I've tried out using exists keyword yesterday and it worked efficiently too, but your's worked more efficient.

Comment: I understand your question, I tried to reduce the set of values with group clause. Distinct clause very slowly on big sets because it needed sort operation. sorry for my English

Comment: Thanks again! Learnt something new. Also, if you have any links to the efficient ways of writing SQL. Please direct me to it.

Comment: Yup, Thats my next step. I've tried reading, and its a bummer. Too cryptic, if you have links that can explain me easily that would be great.

Comment: i started with this book. then i worked with ms sql 2005. then i switched on oracle 10g/11g. now i'm working with sql server 2012. but knowlege useful now http://download.red-gate.com/ebooks/SQL/sql-server-execution-plans.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A sub-query inside a query will be run for each row inside the main query.
 
When having large data inside the main query, that will be a performance anti-pattern (you have 2 sub-queries).

You need a group maximum, that could be achieved with a self left join.

```
SELECT A.id a_id, B.id b_id, C1.timestamp, C1.value
From C C1
INNER JOIN B on B.id = C1.b_id
INNER JOIN A on A.id = B.A_id
LEFT JOIN C C2 on C1.value = C2.value 
and 
C1.timstamp < C2.timestamp
WHERE C1.value IS NOT NULL
and C2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Does it select the distinct C.values from the table? I get a result with repeating 'value' of C using this query.

Comment: Do you have same timestamp && value  in different rows?

Comment: Nope, only 1 row. Although this query is fast, I see repeated values in the result.

Comment: I tried to put distinct and it is taking for ever to run this.

Comment: Does C.Value have a unique constraint? if not then there will be problems.

Comment: use OR condition in OUTER JOIN == very slowly. + you forget () for OR condition

Comment: c.value is not unique, that is the reason i'm trying to pull the value which has max(timestamp)

Comment: As a hint see [the sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/047e0/5) here it seams your are having same C.VALUE, C.TIMESTAMP with diferent ids. May this be a bug in the application

Answer (score -2):

Try one of these. i think i understood your connections. hope it helps. 2nd query might be faster since its trying to gather max timestamp by itself first then joining to other tables ids

```
select A.id, B.id.C.timestamp,c.value
from A 
inner join B on B.B_id = A.id
inner join C on C.C_id = B._B_id
where C.value in (select distinct value from C c2 where c2.value = c.value and c2.value is not null)
and c.timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from C c3 where c3.value = c.value);
```

WITH

```
A_ID AS (
SELECT A.id, B.id
from A 
inner join B on B.A_id = A.id
)
, C_ID AS (
SELECT C_ID, value, max(timestamp) 
from C
where value in (select distinct value from C where value is not null)
)
SELECT a.id, a.b_id, c.B_id, c.timestamp, c.value
FROM A_ID a
inner join C_ID c on c.B_ID = a.B_ID
order by a.id
```